# Access Header,Footer and footnote using iText7

Tags: itext7

How to access the header and footer of the pdf page using itext7. I want to read each page and their artifacts if exists or any other option to get header,footer and footnote?

Any suggestion please?

Comment: What kind of PDFs are you talking about? Random ones from the wild? Tagged ones? Special ones you know the layout metrics for?

Comment: Random once but its very well formatted. These are research papers from the students. sometimes it may or may not have tagged pdfs.

Comment: You mean *"very well formatted"* from a human viewer's point of view? That still leaves a lot of room for interpretation. There are many different ways we humans recognize structure and format in documents, e.g. for headings larger fonts or fatter fonts or preceding section numbers or indentations (inwards or outwards) or..., and for many of these options there are multiple ways to implement them in PDFs. You can use iText to recognize these details (fonts, to a certain extent styles, sizes, positions,...) but you have to implement the interpretation thereof yourself.

Comment: Lets say that all the PDF's are converted (means well formatted) from MS Word.?

Comment: can you share an example? Depending on the MS Word version there may be usable tagging inside.